# j2me: how to show My Location in google map?

Tags: java, google-maps, java-me

Hi 
how i show My Location on Google map ? i see j2me google map application that show My Location , how can i get My Location cordinate ? 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

A good start would be to look at **[Here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/J2ME_Google_Maps_API)**

and to fetch current coordinates **[check the documents here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/)**

Note: It must be a GPS Enabled phone

Comment: Hi , i have samsung corby that havnt GPS , there is googe map application installed on it that have My Location ! how this application get My Location cordinate with out GPS ?

Comment: @mahdi is it showing your coordinates or just a location [like city state,country]  ?

Comment: @mahdi  can you recheck , GPS should be there otherwise how it can locate you upto street level .!! I wonder

Comment: i understand that use cell id

Comment: @mahdi Using cell id it cannot take you upto street level.